# Bypass proxy and capture webpage data from server using HTTP GET request using mitmproxy in Python

Tags: python, html, mitmproxy

I need to bypass proxy using mitmproxy and capture web data using GET request. 
I am using Windows 7 and python 2.7 and mitmproxy python

I tried the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
    This example shows how to build a proxy based on mitmproxy's Flow
    primitives.

    Note that request and response messages are not automatically replied to,
    so we need to implement handlers to do this.
"""
import sys,os
import os
import cStringIO
import threading
import thread
import exceptions
import gc
from libmproxy import proxy, flow
from libmproxy.proxy import config
from libmproxy.proxy import server
from libmproxy.proxy.server import ProxyServer
from libmproxy.platform.windows import TransparentProxy


class MyMaster(flow.FlowMaster):
    def run(self):
        try:
            flow.FlowMaster.run(self)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.shutdown()

    def responseheaders(context, flow):
        ct = flow.response.headers["Content-Type"]
        if ct and len(ct) > 0 and ct[0].startswith("application/"):
            flow.stream = True
            print "streaming"

    def handle_request(self, r):
        print r
        f = flow.FlowMaster.handle_request(self, r)
        if f:
            def run():
                r.reply()
                return f
            threading.Thread(target=run).start()
        else:
            return null

    def handle_response(self, r):
        f = flow.FlowMaster.handle_response(self, r)
        if f:
            def run():
                r.reply()
                return f
            threading.Thread(target=run).start()
        else:
            return null


config = proxy.config.ProxyConfig(
    #ca_file=os.path.expanduser("~\.mitmproxy\mitmproxy-ca.pem")
    confdir=os.path.realpath('.\\conf')#, mode="transparent"
)

gc.enable()

gc.set_threshold(250, 10, 10)

print gc.get_threshold()

state = flow.State()
server = ProxyServer(config, 8080)
#server = TransparentProxy()
m = MyMaster(server, state)

TransparentProxy().setup()

#proxifier = TransparentProxy()

#proxifier.start()

print "got here"

m.run();
```

But got some errors:

```
confdir=os.path.realpath(r'C:\Users\rnive\Documents\certificates')      ``#,mode="transparent"
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'confdir'
```

Any help on rectifying this error.
 Imported the mitmproxy CA by double clicking the mitmproxy-ca-cert.p12 file and loaded mitm.it in chrome browser and got something like :

If you can see this, traffic is not passing through mitmproxy.[image]

Any help on how to congiure and how to rectify the TypeError !

Answer (score 0):

Check the proxy settings in the browser. The error message '... traffic is not passing through mitmproxy'should disappear. In Firefox go to Options|Advanced|Network|Settings. See also [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Firefox).